# TorbenK/TK.CustomMap Xamarin Forms PIN not showing

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding, maps, custom-element

Did anyone experience the following issue?

The pin is nowhere to be found. there are very few samples out there and I can't find one that helps me resolve this issue.
Literally, I copied and pasted the snippet from the project sample from [TK.CustomMap github](https://TK.CustomMap%20github%20sources)

Image with working pin from the original project
[image]

Now, on mine, same snippet. code below
[image]

The pin is working because it clearly shows all the properties I added to it, such as the title. I know this by debugging.  but is not getting into the view. so I believe. I have issues with the binding.

ViewModel

```
/// <summary>
    /// Pins bound to the <see cref="TKCustomMap"/>
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<TKCustomMapPin> Pins
    {
        get { return _pins; }
        set
        {
            if (_pins != value)
            {
                _pins = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Pins");
            }
        }
    }




 MapSpan _mapRegion = MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37.787332, -122.410540), Distance.FromKilometers(2));
            Position _mapCenter;
            ObservableCollection<TKCustomMapPin> _pins;
```

> **constructor**

```
     _mapCenter = new Position(37.787332, -122.410540);
      _pins = new ObservableCollection<TKCustomMapPin>();
    CenterMap();

      void CenterMap()
        {
          var stopOne = new Position(26.0769102268052, -80.2535091197863);
        var pin = new TKCustomMapPin
        {
            Position = stopOne,
            ShowCallout = true,
            IsDraggable = true,
            DefaultPinColor = Color.GreenYellow
            
        };
        _pins.Add(pin);     

    
}
```

**XAML**

```
 <tk:TKCustomMap
            
                        x:Name="mapView" 
                         
                        IsRegionChangeAnimated ="true"
                        HasZoomEnabled="True"
                        MapType="Satellite"
                        WidthRequest="500"
                        HeightRequest="800"
                        IsShowingUser="true" 
                        IsClusteringEnabled="true" 
                        MapRegion="{Binding MapRegion}"
                        Polygons="{Binding Polygons}"
                        CalloutClickedCommand ="{Binding CalloutClickedCommand}"
                        Routes="{Binding Routes}"
                       Pins="{Binding Pins}"/>
```

Comment: "The pin is working but is not getting into the view" - how do you know its working?  "I have issues with the binding" - what "issues" specifically?  "LAT&LON are not accurate" - please be more specific.  If you can't see the pin how do you know its not accurate?  Why are you using wildly invalid values like 44425, 256 and 246 for latitude?

Comment: Have you downloaded the [sample from TK.CustomMap github sources](https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap/tree/Development/Source/Samples/Sample/TK.CustomMap.Sample)? Maybe get that working first, and examine its code.( I've never used TK.CustomMap, so I can't help you further.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve that the first thing I did but thank you

Comment: @Jason, I clarify in the post. I know is working by debugging but is not appearing in the view.